# Game increases node count drastically and freezes

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have created two nodes, a projectile node and a target node, each with their respective categories and when they both contact each other, both are removed and depending on the projectile, even more projectiles appear.

The projectiles also are removed when they touch the edge of the screen.

Everything works fine until after a "wave" of targets (I created a method to occasionally spawn 5 targets in a set design) appear and scroll across the screen and projectiles are all over the place contacting more and more targets, now I would understand the node count increasing, but the amount is no where near the amount, the game then lags to the point of the FPS being 2 FPS and the game eventually freezing and the node count stuck to 700.

**didBeginContact Method**

```
static inline Enemies *nodeFromBody(SKPhysicsBody *body1, SKPhysicsBody *body2, uint32_t category) {
Enemies *node = nil;
if (body1.categoryBitMask & category) {
    node = (Enemies *)body1.node;
}
else if (body2.categoryBitMask & category) {
    node = (Enemies *)body2.node;
}
return node;
}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

SKSpriteNode *projectile = nil;
SKSpriteNode *offScreen = nil;
Enemies *target = nil;

firstBody = contact.bodyA;
secondBody = contact.bodyB;

projectile = nodeFromBody(firstBody, secondBody, projectileCategory);
offScreen = nodeFromBody(firstBody, secondBody, offScreenCategory);
target = nodeFromBody(firstBody, secondBody, targetsCategory);

if (projectile && target) {

    if ([projectile.name isEqualToString:@"firstShot"]) {
        NSLog(@"firstShot");
        [projectile removeAllActions];
        [projectile removeFromParent];
        [ProjectilePatterns pattern1:self spawnPoint:target.position];
        [target removeAllActions];
        [target removeFromParent];
        [Enemies wave1:self spawnPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 525, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 50)];
    }
}
```

**enemyClassMethod**

```
// These are the regular targets, the other method that spawns the wave is essentially creating new enemies and returns them positioned in certain positions.

+(Enemies *)wave1:(SKScene *)scene spawnPoint:(CGPoint)location {

SKAction *delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:5];
SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction *delayAndRemove = [SKAction sequence:@[delay, remove]];

Enemies *enemy1 = [[Enemies alloc] init];
enemy1 = [Enemies spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
enemy1.position = location;
enemy1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:enemy1.size];
enemy1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = targetsCategory;
enemy1.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = projectileCategory;
enemy1.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;

[scene addChild:enemy1];
[enemy1 runAction:delayAndRemove];
[enemy1.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(12, 0)];

return enemy1;
}
```

**Projectile Pattern**

```
+(ProjectilePatterns *)pattern1:(SKScene *)scene spawnPoint:(CGPoint)location {

SKAction *rotate = [SKAction rotateByAngle:1 duration:0.1];
SKAction *rotateForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:rotate];

ProjectilePatterns *patternBomb = [[ProjectilePatterns alloc] init];
patternBomb = [ProjectilePatterns spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"contactBomb"];
patternBomb.position = CGPointMake(location.x + 10, location.y);
patternBomb.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:patternBomb.size];
patternBomb.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = projectileCategory;
patternBomb.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = targetsCategory | offScreenCategory;
patternBomb.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
patternBomb.physicsBody.friction = 0;
patternBomb.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0;
patternBomb.name = @"p1";

ProjectilePatterns *patternBomb2 = [[ProjectilePatterns alloc] init];
patternBomb2 = [ProjectilePatterns spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"contactBomb"];
patternBomb2.position = CGPointMake(location.x - 10, location.y);
patternBomb2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:patternBomb2.size];
patternBomb2.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = projectileCategory;
patternBomb2.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = targetsCategory | offScreenCategory;
patternBomb2.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
patternBomb2.physicsBody.friction = 0;
patternBomb2.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0;
patternBomb2.name = @"p1";

[scene addChild:patternBomb];
[patternBomb runAction:rotateForever];
[patternBomb.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(5, 0)];

[scene addChild:patternBomb2];
[patternBomb2 runAction:rotateForever];
[patternBomb2.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(-5, 0)];

return patternBomb;
return patternBomb2;
}
```

I should also note that the scene's physicsWorld gravity is (0,0). I did this so the impulses movement would be constant.

Comment: post the projectilepatterns code

Comment: My best guess is that two or more bodies remain to be in contact, send their contact events every frame (perhaps even multiple times per frame) and thus creating lots more projectiles than intended. You may need to add a "dontSpawnProjectilesForAWhile" timer or flag that is reset after a set delay, like 1 second.